# Novel about a scientist communicating telepathically with cat-like aliens?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, telepathy

I read a novel around 2009-2010. It was about some girl driving a car with her friends; they got led to some seashore, where there was a scientists' conference. They were discussing something about aliens, then I really don't remember much, but one of the scientists was communicating with these cat-like aliens telepathically.  In the end, I remember that he visited some spaceship near another planet.

Does anyone know what the book is?

Comment: definitely the Disney Classic Cats from Outer Space http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077305/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be Fritz Leiber's [The Wanderer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wanderer_%28Fritz_Leiber_novel%29).

Winner of the Hugo Award for best novel in 1965.

*It was about some girl driving a car with her friends; they got led to some seashore, where there was a scientists' conference.*

> The main protagonists are three longtime friends. Paul Hagbolt is escorting Margo Gelhorn (and her cat, Miaow) to observe the lunar eclipse at an observatory in California.

*They were discussing something about aliens, then I really don't remember much, but one of the scientists was communicating with these cat-like aliens telepathically.*

> Following on a whim a sign advertising a "flying saucer symposium", Paul and Margo fall in with a group of intellectuals, dreamers, charlatans and misfits.

....

> In the saucer Paul meets a being calling itself Tigerishka. A large, female telepathic feline creature, she initially mistakes Miaow as the intelligent being whose thoughts she can hear, and Paul as a "monkey".

*In the end, I remember that he visited some spaceship near another planet.*

> Paul and Don are evacuated in Don's ship, placed into position close to Earth by Tigerishka.